# Selenium - How to click on an 'unclickable' element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using selenium with Python for browser automation. 
On this particular webpage, I need to select the categories for my uploaded video. The categories are shown to have checkboxes to be clicked, but in reality, they are not checkboxes. On clicking them by mouse, the class of the element changes.

Before-

`<span class='foo', id='bar'>`

After-

`<span class='foo.active', id='bar'>`

I am able to locate the element by using both `find_element_by_class_name` and `find_element_by_id`

The problem is not in locating the element, but in clicking on them.

- I have tried `.click()` method, which does not work obviously
- I tried `ActionChains` which gave an error that

> rect is undefined.

- I have tried `execute_script` method which does not throw any error but also does not change anything.

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','foo.active')", element)`

Is there any other method to CHECK that checkbox?

**Update**: I have realized that the element is not in view as it throws an error

> Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

Also, `element.text` returns an empty string.

When I see the webpage in the browser, nothing is blocking the view.

Here is the code:

```
<li id='categoryID1' class='categoryBtn list5'>        
<span class="categoryCheckbox"></span>
<span class="categoryLabel">Funny</span>
<div class="reset"></div>
</li>
```

I tried:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Funny')]")`

It throws this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

**Update 2**: I have also realized that using the `contains(text())` method returns an element which is not in view. On the other hand, when I copied the XPath from the browser and then used the same, it returns an element which can be clicked.

Comment: Can you share what locator are you using?

Comment: I tried both by_id and by_class

Comment: There is not `id` in that `span` node which you have provided, try sharing the whole html line and the locator that you have tried so far

Comment: Please try by xpath (it will always be unique).

Comment: why is .click() not working? If the element is not covered by some other layer, it should work.

Comment: Perhaps it is covered by something. When I used .click() on first element, it worked. But when I do the same on another element, it gives an error `Element <li id="categoryId_10_0" class="categoryBtn listCount_13"> could not be scrolled into view`

Comment: A link to the page would be best. My guess is that you are looking at the wrong part of the page... maybe the mobile version of the site, etc.... something that is not currently displayed and that's why click isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("[contains(@class, 'foo')]")

elem.click()

elem.send_keys(u'\ue007')  (or elem.send_keys(u'\ue00d') )
```

Comment: It throws this error  
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <span class="categoryLabel"> is not reachable by keyboard`

Answer (score 0):

If the class is unique but dynamically changing, you need to search and take partial static value from that class.

In your case, you can try

```
xPath = "//span[contains(@class, 'foo')]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath)
element.click()
```

and if there are multiple matches then you can use the matching index number like below :

```
(//span[contains(@class, 'foo')])[Matching index number]
```

for example, if you are getting match at index number `3` then you can do like below :

```
xPath = "(//span[contains(@class, 'foo')])[3]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath)
element.click()
```

Try to give some delay if the element is present and if you are getting any exceptions while clicking :

```
from time import sleep

sleep(3)
xPath = "(//span[contains(@class, 'foo')])[3]"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xPath)
element.click()
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: I have updated the question. The problem is not in locating the element, but in checking the checkbox. I would update with the original code once the website is up again (it  is down for maintenance right now

Comment: Hi. It is giving an exception `Element <li id="categoryId_10_0" class="categoryBtn listCount_13"> could not be scrolled into view`. 

While it is visible when I see the browser. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: I don't understand your question properly, what is `<span class='foo.active', id='bar'>` and `<li id="categoryId_10_0" class="categoryBtn listCount_13">`? As the class is changing, the locator that you are trying may not work.